# How can I draw a similar graph with ggplot2 to find the difference between two works？

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am reading the book Text Mining with R: A Tidy Approach by Julia Silge & David Robinson to try to find the difference between two works, and not the three in the original book, how can I draw a similar graph with ggplot?

In the original book：

```
    austen <- austen_books() %>% 
  select(-book) %>% 
  mutate(author = "Jane Austen")
bronte <- gutenberg_download(c(1260, 768, 969, 9182, 767)) %>%
  select(-gutenberg_id) %>% 
  mutate(author = "Brontë Sisters")
hgwells <- gutenberg_download(c(35, 36, 5230, 159)) %>% 
  select(-gutenberg_id) %>% 
  mutate(author = "H.G. Wells")

comparison_df <- books %>%
  add_count(author, wt = n, name = "total_word") %>% 
  mutate(proportion = n / total_word) %>% 
  select(-total_word, -n) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = author, values_from = proportion, 
              values_fill = list(proportion = 0)) %>%
  pivot_longer(3:4, names_to = "other", values_to = "proportion")

comparison_df
#> # A tibble: 56,002 x 4
#>   word  `Jane Austen` other          proportion
#>   <chr>         <dbl> <chr>               <dbl>
#> 1 miss        0.00855 Brontë Sisters  0.00342  
#> 2 miss        0.00855 H.G. Wells      0.000120 
#> 3 time        0.00615 Brontë Sisters  0.00424  
#> 4 time        0.00615 H.G. Wells      0.00682  
#> 5 fanny       0.00449 Brontë Sisters  0.0000438
#> 6 fanny       0.00449 H.G. Wells      0        
#> # ... with 5.6e+04 more rows
```

But what if I just want to compare two works?Just like  austen and bronte.

```
comparison_df %>% 
  filter(proportion > 1 / 1e5) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(proportion, `Jane Austen`)) +
  geom_abline(color = "gray40", lty = 2) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = abs(`Jane Austen` - proportion)),
              alpha = 0.1, size = 2.5, width = 0.3, height = 0.3) +
  geom_text(aes(label = word), check_overlap = TRUE, vjust = 1.5) + 
  scale_x_log10(labels = label_percent()) +
  scale_y_log10(labels = label_percent()) + 
  scale_color_gradient(limits = c(0, 0.001), low = "darkslategray4", high = "gray75") + 
  facet_wrap(~ other) + 
  guides(color = FALSE)
```

How can I modify the code above here?

Comment: Your code is giving `Error in add_count(., author, wt = n, name = "total_word") :  object 'books' not found`, please revise it, like this it is not reproducible.

Comment: Yes, it looks like there was a step that combined the austen / bronte / hgwells corpora into an object called `books`, not here.

Comment: Try ```filter(proportion > 1 / 1e5, `Jane Austen` > 1/1e5, other == "Brontë Sisters")```.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete, reproducible solution. The books data wrangling code is a copy&paste of or based on [Text Mining with R: A Tidy Approach, Julia Silge & David Robinson](https://www.tidytextmining.com/tidytext.html).

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  library(tidytext)
  library(stringr)
  library(gutenbergr)
  library(janeaustenr)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(scales)
})

data(stop_words)

austen <- austen_books() %>% 
  select(-book) 
bronte <- gutenberg_download(c(1260, 768, 969, 9182, 767)) %>% 
  select(-gutenberg_id) 
#> Determining mirror for Project Gutenberg from http://www.gutenberg.org/robot/harvest
#> Using mirror http://aleph.gutenberg.org
hgwells <- gutenberg_download(c(35, 36, 5230, 159)) %>% 
  select(-gutenberg_id) 


bind_rows(
  austen %>% mutate(author = "Jane Austen"), 
  bronte %>% mutate(author = "Brontë Sisters"), 
  hgwells %>% mutate(author = "H.G. Wells")
) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
  anti_join(stop_words, by = "word") %>%
  mutate(word = str_extract(word, "[a-z']+")) %>%
  count(author, word, sort = TRUE) %>% 
  add_count(author, name = "total_word") %>% 
  mutate(proportion = n / total_word) %>% 
  select(-total_word, -n) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = author, values_from = proportion, 
              values_fill = list(proportion = 0)) %>%
  pivot_longer(3:4, names_to = "other", values_to = "proportion") %>%
  #
  # to filter author solves the question's problem
  # also filter Jane Austen's values to avoid warnings, log10 was giving
  # Warning messages:
  # 1: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis 
  # 2: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis 
  # 3: Removed 18761 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
  #
  # I have separated the filters to make the code clearer
  # but they can be combined as only one
  #
  filter(proportion > 1/1e5, `Jane Austen` > 1/1e5) %>%
  filter(other == "Brontë Sisters") %>%
  #
  ggplot(aes(proportion, `Jane Austen`)) +
  geom_abline(color = "gray40", lty = 2) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = abs(`Jane Austen` - proportion)),
              alpha = 0.1, size = 2.5, width = 0.3, height = 0.3) +
  geom_text(aes(label = word), check_overlap = TRUE, vjust = 1.5) + 
  scale_x_log10(labels = label_percent()) +
  scale_y_log10(labels = label_percent()) + 
  scale_color_gradient(limits = c(0, 0.001), low = "darkslategray4", high = "gray75") + 
  xlab(label = "Brontë Sisters") +
  guides(color = "none")
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_text).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>